# Parsing json in Angular returns undefined

Tags: angularjs, json

I am new to Angular and I am going through this [tutorial](http://www.tutorials.kode-blog.com/angularjs-debug) and I have problem
with parsing the given json which looks like this:

```
{ "records": [   
    {
        "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City" : "Berlin",
        "Country" : "Germany"   
     },   
     {
        "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "City" : "México D.F.",
        "Country" : "Mexico"   },   
     {
        "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
        "City" : "Graz",
        "Country" : "Austria"   },   
     {
        "Name" : "FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A.",
        "City" : "Madrid",
        "Country" : "Spain"   },   
     {
        "Name" : "Island Trading",
        "City" : "Cowes",
        "Country" : "UK"   
     } 
    ] }
```

The problem is that the json is returned as "undefined" and not shown on page
at all. This is the index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="MyApp">
<head>
<title>AngularJS  Tutorial Series</title>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
</head>
<body>
<div ng-controller="HelloController">Hi {{name}}, welcome to AngularJS Tutorial Series</div>

<div ng-controller="AboutController">Brought to you by {{name}}.</div>

        <h2>Load me some JSON data : )</h2>
        <table ng-controller="HelloController">
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
            <td>{{country.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{country.City}}</td>
            <td>{{country.Country}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
<!-- Angular JS Scripts -->
<script src="js/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<!-- AngularJS Application Specific Scripts -->
<script src="app/app.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/homeController.js"></script>
<script src="app/controllers/aboutController.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

and this is homeController.js file:

```
MyApp.controller('HelloController', hello);

function hello($scope, $http){
    $scope.name = "Rodrick";

    $http.get('countries.json').then(function(data) {
          $scope.countries = data.records;
    });
}
```

Debugging with Google Chrome Developer Tools gives me one warning which says:

> Calling Element.createShadowRoot() for an element which already hosts
>   a shadow root is deprecated. See
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/features/4668884095336448 for more
>   details.

ng-inspector lists countries as undefined under "HelloController".

For the sake of completion, here are app.js and aboutController.js:

app.js:

```
var MyApp = angular.module("MyApp", []);
```

aboutController.js:

```
MyApp.controller('AboutController', about);

function about($scope)
{
    $scope.name = "Kode Blog Tutorials";
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated and thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's `$http` object returns a promise which supports the standard `.then()` function, and a **deprecated** `.success()` function.  The `.then()` returns a standard `response` object;  the deprecated `.success()` function returns a `data` object.

You (correctly) changed your code to the updated `.then()` function, rather than the `.success()` used in the tutorial, but didn't account for the difference in the returned object.

Instead of

```
$http.get('countries.json').then(function(data) {
      $scope.countries = data.records;
});
```

You should use:

```
$http.get('countries.json').then(function(response) {
      $scope.countries = response.data.records;
});
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/O9OyooBZLO9xaCQg8HpH?p=preview

Comment: Thank you very much, @Claies, this solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

**Some of the code changes you have to made in your code :**

- Why use **`ng-controller="HelloController"`** multiple times for the same view ?
  `-->` You have to initialize one controller only once when working on the same view.So, put the **`ng-controller="HelloController"`** in the root element of the view and remove others from the page.
- Why you use separate controller for just displaying the text **`{{name}}`** ?
  `-->` you can do this in same controller `HelloController` only.

**Working demo :**

```js
var myApp = angular.module('myApp',[]);

myApp.controller('HelloController',function ($scope) {
    $scope.countries = [   
    {
        "Name" : "Alfreds Futterkiste",
        "City" : "Berlin",
        "Country" : "Germany"   
     },   
     {
        "Name" : "Centro comercial Moctezuma",
        "City" : "México D.F.",
        "Country" : "Mexico"   },   
     {
        "Name" : "Ernst Handel",
        "City" : "Graz",
        "Country" : "Austria"   },   
     {
        "Name" : "FISSA Fabrica Inter. Salchichas S.A.",
        "City" : "Madrid",
        "Country" : "Spain"   },   
     {
        "Name" : "Island Trading",
        "City" : "Cowes",
        "Country" : "UK"   
     } 
   ];
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="HelloController">
          <table>
          <tr>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>City</th>
            <th>Country</th>
          </tr>
          <tr ng-repeat="country in countries">
            <td>{{country.Name}}</td>
            <td>{{country.City}}</td>
            <td>{{country.Country}}</td>
          </tr>
        </table>
</div>
```